# Enable RDP from command line

Tags: rdp

I'm working remotely via SSH connection and need to use some GUI applications on the remote machine. I do not have an X-Server for X forwarding on my local machine, but a RDP client.

Can I somehow enable RDP via command line?

Usually one would do this in the Settings app in the "Sharing" tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gnome Remote Desktop (RDP/VNC on Ubuntu 22.04 and other recent versions) can be enabled through command line by using the `grdctl` command.

The command line parameters are documented in the man pages of the cli tool, e.g. [here](https://www.mankier.com/1/grdctl).

When using it through SSH, I initially had the problem that

- it was not working with `sudo`
- using the tool without `sudo` blocked indefinetly because it was waiting for a graphical admin prompte on the desktop of the remote host.

The only workaround I found so far was to initially configure RDP direclty on the remote host first.

Answer (score -1):

You could install, then start **x11vnc** on the remote machine, then use a VNC client to connect. If you require RDP specifically, then [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/567371/connect-using-windows-rdp) (which also uses **x11vnc**, but with the **xrdp** connector) is your best bet.

However, if VNC is adequate, then it's pretty simple. Note that the three steps I list here do not provide any security! If the remote machine can be accessed by anyone other than yourself, make sure to `man x11vnc` and put a password on the remote x11vnc session.

1. On the remote machine, install **x11vnc**

`sudo apt install x11vnc`

2. On the remote machine, start **x11vnc**

`x11vnc -forever`

3. On your machine, connect to the remote machine using your VNC client (e.g.  **Remmina**)

Once you're finished, hit CTRL-C on your remote machine to exit **x11vnc**.

If you intend to use **x11vnc** more commonly, as I stated above, I recommend setting a password with `x11vnc -usepw`, and then examining some of the more advanced options it offers with `man x11vnc`. It's a powerful tool.

Comment: This is not what I was looking for. Newer versions of Ubuntu (e.g. 22.04) have RDP and also VNC support included in the Destkop settings. It can be enable through the Destop settings app and I was wondering if there's a cli-command or text file etc. to do this configuration from within the terminal wihtout gui interaction.